# UIScrollView doesn't respond to setZoomScale:

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview

What am I doing wrong? Here is how I create + populate my scrollView

```
    -(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bigimage.jpg"]];
    imgView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;

    scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
    scrollView.contentSize = imgView.frame.size;

    scrollView.minimumZoomScale =  scrollView.frame.size.width / scrollView.contentSize.width * 0.99;
    scrollView.maximumZoomScale =  2;

    [self.view addSubview:scrollView];


[scrollView addSubview:imgView];

    [scrollView setZoomScale:0.5 animated:YES];
    NSLog(@"current zoomScale: %f", scrollView.zoomScale);
    [imgView release];
}
```

The NSLogged zoomScale is 1.0, and the image is clearly shown at full size. Pinch zoom does not do anything.
I've tried almost everything I can find on the net, but everybody seems to be doing exactly this, and it works for them.

Help is vastly appreciated!

Comment: Great question, as evidenced by it showing up as #1 in Google under UIScrollview setzoomscale doesn't work :)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

A `UIScrollView` will not zoom unless it has its `delegate` property set to a valid `UIScrollViewDelegate` that responds to

```
- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView;
```

Check out  **[the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIScrollViewDelegate/viewForZoomingInScrollView:)**.

Comment: THANK YOU!
I just found this somewhere else two seconds ago and had come back to fix my question. Clearly I'm not reading the docs hard enough.